# tkz-fct not creating a visible graph on one tab (works fine in another tab)

Tags: pdftex, tkz-fct

I am starting one plot on one of the tabs, which gives me the error as follows:

```
set table "Sample* Paper*1.tkzfct.table"; set format "%.5f" ^ "Sample Paper 1.tkzfct.gnuplot" line 1: cannot open table output file system error: Invalid argument
```

When I was troubleshooting, I pasted the code to another tab which has a working tkz plot, and it works.

My LaTeX has the shell escape thing on the `pdfLaTeX`, so that should not be the issue.

Comment: Welcome on SE! This seams like an interesting question. In order to answer it quickly we need a minimal working example.

Comment: hmm i think this is best illustrated with a video, will that be okay? because the issue is that the code does work on one document but doesnt work on the other.